# Nav bar Active tab color change

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

My code is not working I don't know why?

someone, please help me out.

I am not able to add a class name to the active nav bar

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li class="nav-list"><a href="home.html" class="navlink">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-list"><a href="aboutme.html" class="navlink">About me</a></li>
        <li class="nav-list"><a href="work.html" class="navlink">Work</a></li>
        <li class="nav-list"><a href="contact.html" class="navlink">Contact me</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

css

```
.nav-list a.active{
    color:rgb(28, 162, 224);
}
```

javaScript

```
const currentlocation = location.href;
const menuitem = document.querySelectorAll('nav-list a');
const menulenght = menuitem.length;

for(let i = 0; i < menulenght; i++){
    if(menuitem[i].href === currentlocation){
        menuitem[i].className =  'active';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** You have to use `.` for class selector as:

```
document.querySelectorAll( '.nav-list a' );
```

**2)** You have to use `add` method to add a new class as:

```
menuitem[i].classList.add( "active" )
```

**JS**

```
const currentlocation = location.href;
const menuitem = document.querySelectorAll( '.nav-list a' );

for ( let i = 0; i < menuitem.length; i++ ) {
    if ( menuitem[i].href === currentlocation ) {
        menuitem[i].classList.add( "active" )
    }
}
```

Also, there is a typo in your current code: `lenght` instead of `length`